# Is it okay?? Any lambda is equal to zero

Tags: optimization

In optimization problem using Lagrange multiplier..

$f(x, y, z) = x + 2z$, subject to $g_1(x, y, z) = x + y + z = 1$, $g_2(x; y; z) = 2x + z = 2$

Find $x, y, x, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$

.............................................

I couldn't find the right solution using with equation $ℒ = f(x)-\lambda_1 g_1(x, y, z)-λ_2g_2(x, y, z)=0$
Should I have doubts about the problem?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: You might try graphing the function and constraints to understand why there are no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case.
let $$f(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=x+2z+\lambda_1(x+y+z-1)+\lambda_2(2x+z-2)$$
then we get

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1+\lambda_1+2\lambda_2$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\lambda_1$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=2+\lambda_1+\lambda_2$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_1}=x+y+z-1$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_2}=2x+z-2$$
The system has no solutions, since we get $$\lambda_2=-\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$\lambda_2=-2$$

we must solve
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_1}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_2}=0$$

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, since this problem is given two constraints, does not Lagrangian need to include both constraints?

Comment: Yes this is true, i will correct my solution

Comment: Thank you. I proceeded in exactly the same way as above. Could you find the appropriate lambda 1 and lambda 2? I can't.....

Comment: One moment please, i think there is no solution.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the order or linearity of the objective function. HBU?

Answer (score 0):

The two constraints define a feasible set which is a line

$$
g_1(x,y,z)\cap g_2(x,y,z) = L
$$

$$
L\to (x,y,z)^{\dagger} = (1,0,0)^{\dagger}+\mu(1,1,-2)^{\dagger}
$$

so along $L$ the objective function which is linear, is unbounded.